# Where do I find the source code for execve()?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Could you give me the source code for `execve()` system call (*exec* family). I'm working with Linux.

Comment: man execve tells you everything you need to know. What do you mean by “give me the source code for”? Some snippet as examples of use?

Comment: You mean: sudo get me the source code for execve

Answer (score 7):

execve() calls sys_execve() which calls do_execve(), which is where the action is: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c#l1376

Answer (score 3):

Youmight look at [sys_execve at arch/x86/kernel/process.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/kernel/process.c;h=d8286ed54ffaba86a0882baae443cd9d267b5a30;hb=HEAD#l295) which calls [do_execve at fs/exec.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c;h=c62efcb959c73fc458367d811c576e634fb49634;hb=HEAD#l1373).

Answer (score 3):

The `execve()` entry point is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L304), in the Linux Cross-Reference page. You can follow the function references ([`do_execve()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/fs/exec.c#L1376) is probably what you actually need) to see the source code.

Comment: +1 for linking to LXR instead of git.  The source code is far more usable as hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the linux source code at the [kernel page](http://www.kernel.org)
To browse inline, use the [git browsing facility](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;h=0a8aeaaf4acbc86ac682f18632b8070c1c6b7ba1;hb=HEAD)